# how to initialize array of STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(15 downto 0) with data stored in BRAM

Tags: vhdl

I have some Filter coefficients in BRAM those coefficients need to be written into an array to perform convolution. I have created an array using type and assigned it to a signal. That signal I have port mapped to DATA_OUT of BRAM. it's giving an error "expecting STD_LOGIC_VECTOR"

I've tried writing the data in an array with for loop. It results in an error "indices is not a STD_LOGIC_VECTOR"

my type declaration

```vhdl
TYPE coeff_pipe IS ARRAY(0 TO 15) OF std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
Signal coeff:coeff_pipe;
```

my for loop is like this

```
for i in 0 to  loop
    coeff(i) <= data_out_BRAM(i);   end loop;
```

Help me with suitable changes in my code to make it work

Comment: What is "data_out_BRAM(i);" because as far as I know a BRAM maximum width is 36 bits so, apart from the data types which do not match at all, (but that can syntactically be fixed), how do you plan to read 8*16=128 bits from a 36 bit wide BRAM?

Comment: You have to get your BRAM values one by one (one at each clock cycle). Or if you wrap some words together, 4 by 4 but you can't read your BRAM in one time.

Comment: Hi Gautitho I have to get my BRAM Values one by one

Answer (score 0):

You mix the **for loop** behavior in a coding language (C) and in a hardware descritpion language (VHDL). In a coding language, if you write a **for loop**, processor will execute the content of the loop several times in row sequentially (one after one). In an HDL, **for loop** is used to instanciate several times the same circuit with different inputs/outputs. There is no time notion in a **for loop**.

In your case, you have to use a sequential process and increment your BRAM address :

```
process(clk, rst)
begin

  if rst = '1' then
    addr_BRAM     <= (others => '0');
    addr_BRAM_d   <= (others => '0');
    ram_init_en   <= '1';
    ram_init_en_d <= '0';
    coeff         <= (others => (others => '0'));
  elsif rising_edge(clk) then

    addr_BRAM_d   <= addr_BRAM  ; -- Delay of 1 clk cycle 
    ram_init_en_d <= ram_init_en; -- Delay of 1 clk cycle

    -- Init done
    if addr_BRAM = x"1111" then
      ram_init_en <= '0';
    end if;

    -- Increment BRAM address
    if ram_init_en = '1' then
      addr_BRAM  <= std_logic_vector(unsigned(addr_BRAM) + 1);
    end if;

    -- Get data one cycle after set address because a BRAM doesn't answer instant, it answers in one clk cycle. 
    if ram_init_en_d = '1' then
      coeff(to_integer(unsigned(addr_BRAM_d))) <= data_out_BRAM;
    end if;    

  end if;

end process;
```

Comment: If you don't understand, don't hesitate to ask. I think you should read some courses about HDL philosophy because it's really different than programming languages.